# I130 rejection before 2010, applying for canada TRV now

Tags: visas, usa, canada, visa-refusals

i had an I130 rejection before 2010 to the USA (I130 is my sister sponsoring me and my dad and mom to go to the USA and get a green card)

I need to include the reason for rejection right? well i have no idea and the papers are missing and the website of UCIS doesn't display the information needed (i have the case number) and calling them only directs me to the website, what can i do? can i write that i forgot the reason or what? i also forgot the year of applying and rejection.

thanks.

Comment: If you can’t remember the details then yes, just state you were refused and explain you don’t remember the reason. Or you could try asking your sister?

Answer (score 1):

The TRV application form for Canada asks:

> b)  Have you ever been refused a visa or permit, denied entry or ordered to leave Canada or any other country or territory?

If you can’t remember the details, just answer "Yes" to the question, provide the case number and explain that you don’t remember the reason.